# Two possible senses of a random variable being a function of another random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Given two random variables X and Y (assumed measurable as usual), consider two conditions:

1. There is a (not necessarily measurable) function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $Y = f(X)$ holds.
2. There is a Borel-measurable function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $Y = f(X)$ almost surely.

Does the first condition imply the second condition?

In other words, if X determines Y in the set theory sense, does X determine Y in the probability theory sense too?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then I believe the answer you're looking for is YES!

**Proposition**: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and suppose $X: \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable. Suppose further $Y : \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$ is $\sigma(X)/\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb{R}}$-measurable. Then there is some measurable function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $Y = f(X)$ ($P$-a.s.).

**Proof**: First assume that $Y$ is simple. Then we have that $Y = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k \, 1_{X^{-1}(E_i)}$ for some scalars $\lambda_k$ and sets $E_i \in \mathcal{B}_{\Bbb{R}}$. Then $Y = f(X)$ where $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k\, 1_{E_i}(x)$. Now, for a general $Y$, let $Y_n$ be $\sigma(X)/\mathcal{B}$ measurable simple functions which converge to $Y$ ($P$-a.s.). Then for each $n$ there exists some measurable $f_n : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $Y_n = f_n(X)$. Define $f = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n$. Then $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is measurable and $Y = f(X)$ ($P$-a.s.).

Comment: In view of your proposition, my question reduces to the question of whether the first condition in my post implies the condition $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(X)$, but the reduced question seems nontrivial still.